# ifelse ignoring first test in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data.frame with 3 columns:

```
df <- structure(list(ParticipantID = c("R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7", "R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv", 
"R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77", "R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa", "R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9", 
"R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl", "R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K", "R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw", 
"R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7", "R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE", "R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84", 
"R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9", "R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF", "R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA", 
"R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT", "R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7", "R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv", 
"R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77", "R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa", "R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9", 
"R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl", "R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K", "R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw", 
"R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7", "R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE", "R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84", 
"R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9", "R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF", "R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA", 
"R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT", "R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7", "R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv", 
"R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77", "R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa", "R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9", 
"R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl", "R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K", "R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw", 
"R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7", "R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE", "R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84", 
"R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9", "R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF", "R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA", 
"R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT", "R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7", "R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv", 
"R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77", "R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa", "R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9", 
"R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl", "R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K", "R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw", 
"R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7", "R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE", "R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84", 
"R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9", "R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF", "R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA", 
"R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT", "R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7", "R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv", 
"R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77", "R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa", "R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9", 
"R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl", "R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K", "R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw", 
"R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7", "R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE", "R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84", 
"R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9", "R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF", "R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA", 
"R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT", "R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7", "R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv", 
"R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77", "R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa", "R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9", 
"R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl", "R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K", "R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw", 
"R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7", "R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE", "R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84", 
"R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9", "R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF", "R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA", 
"R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT", "R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7", "R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv", 
"R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77", "R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa", "R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9", 
"R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl", "R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K", "R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw", 
"R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7", "R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE", "R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84", 
"R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9", "R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF", "R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA", 
"R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT"), Question = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", 
"Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", 
"Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", 
"Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", 
"Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", 
"Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", 
"Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", 
"Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q5", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", 
"Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q6", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", 
"Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", "Q7", 
"Q7"), Scores = c("4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "3", 
"4", "3", "1", "1", "4", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "3", "1", 
"", "3", "1", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "1", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "4", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4")), row.names = c(NA, -105L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to change to values of the column `Score`, which consists of character values that represent numbers (e.g. "1", "2", etc) to the character values "correct" or "incorrect". For this, I am trying to use code to change the values of `Score` depending of the value of `Score` and the value of `Question`.

In pseudocode:
If `Question` is equal to "Q1" and `Score` is equal to "3", change the value to "correct". Else, change it to "incorrect".

I am trying the following:

```
df$Score <- ifelse(df$Question == "Q1" & df$Score == "3", "correct", "incorrect")
```

However, this code ignores the first condition, because it changes all the values in Score depending on the condition of Score == 3 (so, it does this for all rows, and not only for those where `Question` is equal to "Q1".

I also tried:

```
df$Scores[df$Question == "Q1"] <- ifelse(df$Scores == "3","correct","incorrect")
```

This works with a warning:

> Warning message: In df$Scores[df$Question == "Q1"] <- ifelse(df$Scores
> == "3", "correct",  :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

However, if I keep using the code above for Q2, and change the condition of the ifelse to, e.g, Score being equal to "1", then everything gets the "incorrect" label.

This is as far as I could go. I could swear I am using the ifelse() function correctly, but apparently that's not the case.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You have a typo in the first version. It should be `df$Scores == "3"`, not `df$Score == "3"`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. `df$Score <- ifelse(df$Question == "Q1" & df$Scores == "3", "correct", "incorrect")` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close with your last attempt, you'd just need to ensure you subset as well within the `ifelse` statement as below:

```
df$Scores[df$Question == "Q1"] <- ifelse(df$Scores[df$Question == "Q1"] == "3", 
                                         "correct", 
                                         "incorrect")
```

Output:

```
df[1:20, ]

       ParticipantID Question    Scores
1  R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7       Q1 incorrect
2  R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv       Q1 incorrect
3  R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77       Q1 incorrect
4  R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa       Q1 incorrect
5  R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9       Q1 incorrect
6  R_1Qrvncp9IyGCQhl       Q1 incorrect
7  R_2QJNX5jr05Exz5K       Q1 incorrect
8  R_3s5DrmDel4LJAlw       Q1 incorrect
9  R_Ubx6wZtZejtEUH7       Q1   correct
10 R_3kzBb3CRtJzBPEE       Q1 incorrect
11 R_3IRbEYxYDSexz84       Q1   correct
12 R_3EHnuMJ1b48jvA9       Q1 incorrect
13 R_QhIZ4MiZ0UVdUoF       Q1 incorrect
14 R_1Kg2e4K2IGunWoA       Q1 incorrect
15 R_2UYIgsOvy0UVsqT       Q1 incorrect
16 R_3m49eVj2HUtJUT7       Q2         3
17 R_UQMpKBVCiSCXCvv       Q2         3
18 R_11ZLsdTLX0zwe77       Q2         3
19 R_1H1sGpFS6srJHZa       Q2         3
20 R_2OU6OMBsaEyGdh9       Q2         1
```

Alternatively (using pure `ifelse` logic while doing the assignment to the full `Scores` vector, as in your first attempt), you could try a nested `ifelse`:

```
df$Scores <- ifelse(df$Question == "Q1",
                   ifelse(
                     df$Scores == "3", "correct", "incorrect"
                   ),
                   df$Scores)
```

Comment: Thanks! I would not have guessed I needed to subset Q==1 twice. I tried with the nested ifelses also but now seeing your example I understand how they work. Many thanks!